# how to set CATextLayer text vertical position?

Tags: ios, uilabel, calayer, catextlayer

I create `UILabel` and `CATextLayer` in my app using following code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.textLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 90, 20, 20)];
    self.textLabel.text = @"1";
    self.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
    self.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.view addSubview:self.textLabel];

    self.textLayer = [CATextLayer layer];
    [self.textLayer setString:@"1"];
    [self.textLayer setFont:(__bridge CFTypeRef)([UIFont systemFontOfSize:12])];
    self.textLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
    self.textLayer.frame = CGRectMake(70, 90, 50, 20);
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:self.textLayer];
}
```

and the result is

[image]

The red one is `UILabel`, the green one is `CALayer. I want to know how to vertical align the text in`CALayer`, as the`UILabel` shows.

Comment: @Tark This question is not a duplicate. This question is in regards to iOS. iOS hasn't got layoutManager available as of iOS 11.

Answer (score 10):

Actually, this is what works for me:

```
self.layer.addSublayer(textLayer)
textLayer.font = font
textLayer.fontSize = font.pointSize
textLayer.frame = CGRectMake(self.layer.bounds.origin.x, ((self.layer.bounds.height - textLayer.fontSize) / 2) - lineWidth, self.layer.bounds.width, self.layer.bounds.height)
textLayer.alignmentMode - kCAAlignmentCenter
textLayer.contentsScale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
```

LineWidth is what I use to "frame" my bounding area.  This keeps my text centered vertically and horizontally.

Answer (score 9):

The correct answer is found [here](http://lists.apple.com/archives/quartz-dev/2008/Aug/msg00016.html) in Objective-C and **works for iOS**. It works by subclassing the `CATextLayer` and overriding the `drawInContext` function.

However, I've made some improvements to the code, as shown below, using David Hoerl's code as a basis. The changes come solely in recalculating the vertical position of the text.

Here is the code for Swift users:

```
class LCTextLayer : CATextLayer {

// REF: http://lists.apple.com/archives/quartz-dev/2008/Aug/msg00016.html
// CREDIT: David Hoerl - https://github.com/dhoerl 
// USAGE: To fix the vertical alignment issue that currently exists within the CATextLayer class. Change made to the yDiff calculation.

override init!() {
    super.init()
}

override init!(layer: AnyObject!) {
    super.init(layer: layer)
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(layer: aDecoder)
}

override func drawInContext(ctx: CGContext!) {
    let height = self.bounds.size.height
    let fontSize = self.fontSize
    let yDiff = (height-fontSize)/2 - fontSize/10

    CGContextSaveGState(ctx)
    CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0.0, yDiff)
    super.drawInContext(ctx)
    CGContextRestoreGState(ctx)
}
}
```

Comment: Note for macOS devs: if the view containing the layer has a traditional coordinate system (not flipped), you'll need to multiply yDiff by -1

Answer (score 5):

Swift 3 version of @iamktothed's answer:

```
class VerticallyCenteredTextLayer : CATextLayer {

    // REF: http://lists.apple.com/archives/quartz-dev/2008/Aug/msg00016.html
    // CREDIT: David Hoerl - https://github.com/dhoerl
    // USAGE: To fix the vertical alignment issue that currently exists within the CATextLayer class.

    override func draw(in ctx: CGContext) {
        let fontSize = self.fontSize
        let height = self.bounds.size.height
        let deltaY = (height-fontSize)/2 - fontSize/10

        ctx.saveGState()
        ctx.translateBy(x: 0.0, y: deltaY)
        super.draw(in: ctx)
        ctx.restoreGState()
    }
}
```

Comment: Note for macOS devs: if the view containing the layer has a traditional coordinate system (not flipped), you'll need to multiply deltaY by -1.

Comment: @Bryan Thank you hero! I've been searching for hours!!! Makes a lot of sense too!

Comment: This works for me too in Swift 5.3. However, it doesn't center the text if it is multiline (word wrapped). It appears to be centering on the first line of text, which makes me believe it is setting a boundary at the center of the layer and any wrapped text gets pushed down. What needs to be done to this to vertically center multi line (or word wrapped) text?  I'm writing for macOS and I have set the deltaY to be multiplied by -1.

Answer (score 3):

As per CATextLayer's documentation, there is no option to vertically align a text. The only option is to reposition the text layer so as to align well with the label. Here's the code to achieve the same

```
CGFloat offsetY = 0;
UIFont *textFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f];
//if system version is grater than 6
if(([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:@"6" options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedDescending)){
    offsetY = (textFont.capHeight - textFont.xHeight);
}

self.textLayer = [CATextLayer layer];
self.textLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
self.textLayer.frame = CGRectMake(70, 90+offsetY, 50, 20);
[self.view.layer addSublayer:self.textLayer];
[self.textLayer setContentsScale:[UIScreen mainScreen].scale];
[self.textLayer setForegroundColor: [UIColor blackColor].CGColor];
[self.textLayer setString:@"1"];
[self.textLayer setFont:(__bridge CFTypeRef)(textFont)];
[self.textLayer setFontSize:14.0f];
```

The result is

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
{
    CATextLayer *label = [[CATextLayer alloc] init];
    [label setFont:@"Helvetica-Bold"];
    [label setFontSize:16];
    [label setFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, NSWidth(self.frame) / 2., NSHeight(self.frame))];
    [label setString:@"ON"];
    [label setAlignmentMode:kCAAlignmentCenter];

    [label setForegroundColor:[[NSColor whiteColor] CGColor]];

    _rootLayer.layoutManager = [CAConstraintLayoutManager layoutManager];
    [label addConstraint:[CAConstraint
                          constraintWithAttribute:kCAConstraintMidY
                          relativeTo:@"superlayer"
                          attribute:kCAConstraintMidY]];
    [label addConstraint:[CAConstraint
                          constraintWithAttribute:kCAConstraintMidX relativeTo:@"superlayer" attribute:kCAConstraintMidX]];
    [_rootLayer addSublayer:label];

}
```

Comment: I'm having problems finding CAConstraint for iOS is this an OSX class only?